# How to find conditional expectation?

Tags: normal-distribution, conditional-expectation

We have ξ and η independent random variables with normal distribution ~ N(0,1). How to find variance of E(2ξ+η|ξ+η)?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! Not sure what you mean by variance of $\mathbb{E}[2\xi + \eta|\xi + \eta]$. The expectation of any random variable is constant, therefore it has zero variance.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. but conditional expectation is a random variable too. So it is not 0.

Comment: +1 You are right. So why not find it directly, in other words, find the pdf and compute the expected value, and then compute the variance, like you would for any other random variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, it would seem that
$$
E[2\xi+\eta|\xi+\eta] = (\xi+\eta)+E[\xi|\xi+\eta] = (\xi+\eta) + \frac{\xi+\eta}2 = \frac{3(\xi+\eta)}2.
$$
In first step, I use $E[\xi+\eta|\xi+\eta] = \xi+\eta$, and in the second step, I used that $\xi$ and $\eta$ are i.i.d., so if you know their sum, your best guess for either one is the average (it is also easy to prove this fact).

It should now be simple to compute the variance straight from definition.

Comment: +1, very clever